# Simultaneous Recording and Real-Time Display Using ffmpeg with DeckLink

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently working with a DeckLink Duo card, specifically utilizing port 2. My objective is to use FFmpeg to ingest RAW HD SDI, save it as an MP4 file, and concurrently display the incoming SDI video on the computer screen in real-time.

I have experimented with various FFmpeg command lines, combining decklink and sdl options, to achieve this dual functionality:

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -i 'DeckLink Duo@2' -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f sdl "My Screen"
```

However, I am encountering challenges in achieving both recording and real-time display simultaneously.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to enable the concurrent recording and display of SDI video using DeckLink with ffmpeg.

Comment: What "challenges" do you have? What happens? What error messages fo you get, if any?